# Extract p-value from a varCompFixEf object in the package varComp (extract p-values in var comp package)

Tags: r, p-value, varcomp

I am trying to extract the p-value for a fixed effect from a linear mixed effect model specified in the "varComp" package (using the varComp()) function.

Using 
`summary(model)$fixef`

Enables me to extract the output tables for the fixed effects:

```
                 Estimate  Std. Error        Lower         Upper     t value Scale        Df     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -10.713652206 0.117801777 -10.94843869 -10.478865719 -90.9464396     1  72.85480 9.330543e-77
snp1GG       -0.077577464 0.082086180  -0.24805847   0.092903541  -0.9450734     1  21.46851 3.551374e-01
SexM          0.198189186 0.071772595   0.05363726   0.342741109   2.7613490     1  45.06217 8.298709e-03
age.years    -0.007443209 0.004365628  -0.01603946   0.001153045  -1.7049574     1 261.52372 8.938987e-02
Average.BCS  -0.065434158 0.030612086  -0.12568251  -0.005185811  -2.1375269     1 291.94797 3.338572e-02
Seasonwet    -0.140436443 0.049207634  -0.23732376  -0.043549130  -2.8539564     1 265.21902 4.658585e-03
```

I would like to extract the p-value for snp1GG, however, because the output table is a varCompFixEf object I can't use code such as `summary(model)$fixef[2,8]` to extract it.

Does anyone know how to just get the p-value from one fixed effect in a varCompFixEf object?

Comment: It's removed from cran, so i cannot install it. From reading the source code (https://rdrr.io/cran/varComp/src/R/fixef.varComp.R), you can try attr(summary(model)$fixef, 'anova') or attr(model$fixef,'anova')

Comment: @StupidWolf that worked perfectly!! thank you so much!